# Fetch the value of nested object from API response

Tags: typescript, angular7

If I have the following API response, how to fetch the value `player` using `ngFor` in angular 7?

[image]

Comment: post what you have done so far

Comment: `<div class="col" *ngFor="let parent of summeryDetail.match_details">                         
      <div class="text-center pt-3" *ngFor="let child1 of parent.team_a">
        <h3 class="mb-0" *ngFor="let child2 of child1.teama_player">{{ child2.player }}</h3>
      </div>`

Comment: @KrishnamoorthyM `match_details` is an object so this will not work!

Comment: @Prashant Pimpale , Okay what's the changes needs to be done... how to handle this nested object.

Comment: @KrishnamoorthyM Please provide the Sample JSON in the form of code. so will try

Comment: @KrishnamoorthyM Added an answer pls check

Comment: @PrashantPimpale it's working. thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the list of all players i.e `teama_player` list so you can just:

```
<div class="col" *ngFor="let obj of summeryDetail.match_details.team_a.teama_player">
   {{obj.player}}
</div>
```